# PHP DOMDocument object has null documentElement for valid XML

Tags: php, xml, rss, domdocument

The XML I'm working with is actually the RSS feed located at http://www.gjc.org/cgi-bin/rssjobs.pl

It seems to validate via the W3C RSS Feed and XML validators.  When I do the following, I just get `null`.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument($xml);
$dom->loadXML($xml);
var_dump($dom->documentElement);
```

Am I missing something obvious?  Maybe an encoding problem?  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `DOMDoc` the class is `DOMDocument`. Is it a typo or some custom library?

Comment: Because with `DOMDocument` it works https://eval.in/889459

Comment: Aha, I finally got it to give me an actual error!  "Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0x96 0x20 0x47 0x49 in Entity, line: 257 in "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the encoding to make it work, try the following:

```
$xml = file_get_contents("http://www.gjc.org/cgi-bin/rssjobs.pl");
$xml = mb_convert_encoding($xml, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");

$dom = new DOMDocument($xml);
$dom->loadXML($xml);
var_dump($dom->documentElement);
```

This will convert the characters accordingly.